# How can i show the items for a specific category

Tags: javascript

Hi i want to show the items for a specific category only, so when the user is on the html page they can pick a category and then it should show the items for that category only, its the "vareKategori" where you can choose.[See the frontend her][1]
for now i can display all the items but i can't get products for only one category. It would meen so much if somebody could show me how to do it, thx.

Please help,its for an exam project.

```
this is my code for now:
// Jeg laver en function som tager userinputtet fra det de skriver. Det gør jeg både for nyt userID og nyt password



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const varer = document.getElementById("varer").value;
    const pris = document.getElementById("pris").value;
    const vareKategori = document.getElementById("vareKategori").value;
    const billede = document.getElementById("billede").value

    const opretVare = {
      varer: varer,
      pris: pris,
      vareKategori: vareKategori,
      billede: billede
    };

    fetch("http://localhost:8200/varer/createvarer", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(opretVare),
      })
      //converter det til Json
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        if (response) {
          location.href = "/varer.html";
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        window.alert("Der skete en fejl");
      });
  });
});


async function getGoods() {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8200/varer/getproducts")
  const result = await response.json()
  return result
}

async function deleteGoods(id) {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8200/varer/getproducts/" + id, { 
    method: 'DELETE'
  })
  const result = await response.json()
  return result
}

function renderTable(goods) {
    const table = document.getElementById('varerTable');
    let tableHtml = `
      <tr>
      <th>
      <label Varekategori:</label>
      <select name="kategori" id="kategori">
          <option value="mad">Mad</option>
          <option value="drikkelse">Drikkelse</option>
      </select>
      </th>
      
      <th>Vare</th>     
       <th>Pris</th>
        <th>Billede</th>
      </tr>`;
    for (const row of goods){
      tableHtml += `
        <tr>
          <td>${row.vareKategori}</td>
          <td>${row.varer}</td>
          <td>${row.pris}</td>
          <td><img src="${row.billede}" style="height:100px;width000px;"</td>
          <td><button onclick = "handleDelete(${row.id})"> Delete </button></td>
          <td><button onclick ="toDo"> Edit </button></td>
        </tr>
      `;
    }
    table.innerHTML = tableHtml;
}

async function handleDelete(id) {
  try {
    await deleteGoods(id)
    const goods = await getGoods()
    renderTable(goods)
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
  }  
}

async function handleLoad() {
  try {
    const goods = await getGoods()
    renderTable(goods)
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
  }  
} 
document.getElementById("clickMe").addEventListener('click', handleLoad);
```

**routes**

```
router.put("/opdater_products/:varer", (req, res)=>{
  let category = req.params.varer;
  if(products[category]){
    products[category] = req.body.pris;
    res.status(200).json({[category]:products[category]});
  }
  else{
    res.send(404)
  }
  });
```

**model**

```
class Goods {
    constructor(varer, pris, vareKategori, billede) {
      this.varer = varer;
      this.pris = pris;
      this.vareKategori = vareKategori;
      this.billede = billede;
    }
  }
  module.exports = Goods;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to make sense of, but maybe `Array.prototype.filter` is what you want? Like if you have a list of products,

```
let categoryToSort = 'foo';
let products = [
  {
    'name': 'whatever',
    'categories': ['foo', 'baz'],
  },
  {
    'name': 'baz',
    'category': ['bar'],
  }
]; 

// Filter
let filteredProducts = products.filter(p => p.category.includes(categoryToSort));

// Output filtered array 
console.log(filteredProducts);

/**
output:
  {
    'name': 'whatever',
    'category': ['foo', 'baz'],
  },
**/
```